# Symfony2 routing without prefix

Tags: symfony, routes

In my Symfony project, I have:

1. example.com/**user**/username => go to user profile
2. example.com/**blog**/theweathertoday => go to a dynamic page post blog
3. example.com/**whoarewe** => a static page defined in routig.yml

And I would like to implement:

1. example.com/username => go to user profile
2. example.com/theweathertoday => go to a dynamic page post blog
3. example.com/whoarewe => a static page

Could you tell me what is the best way to:

- separate user from blog article from the site pages ? (controller, service, ... ?)
- how to make sure the user does not register with a restricted name, like "whoarewe" which is defined in routing.yml ?

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `routing.yml` file is just one way to load routes, but there are [many other ways](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-include-external-resources). One way, which you may need, is a [custom route loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html).

Since route loaders are defined as services, you can inject other services into them, such as a username checker which can also be re-used by the part of your application that validates new user registration.

Absent of doing something like this, you'd need to route all traffic that matches `^/[^/]+` to a sort of intermediary front-controller that would take the matched parameter and decide how to forward it.

The full answer to your question is going to be a decent amount of work, but hopefully this gets you started in the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

to change example.com/user/username to example.com/username i think you just have to remove **/user** in one of your **routing.yml** files. same with **/blog**. These files can be found under your Bundle directories in te Resources/config directory or in your app/config directory.

Comment: i undestand what you are saying but this doesn't resolve the conflict between the 3 types of pages. For a example a user called "whoarewe" will be in confilct with the page "whoarewe"

Comment: if username and theweathertoday  then it is not possible. But what is possible is to change the order: example.com/{username}/user